# Return innerHTML as a UL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting my objects returned as a list of things stuck together in the view.  I want to separate them out into a nice list.

What am I missing to do that?

**HTML**

```
 <div id="myPlace">
 </div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
  for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    var place = results[i];
    console.log(place)
    document.getElementById("myPlace").innerHTML += place.name + " - " + place.vicinity 
  }
}
```

Comment: you could append a <br/> tag?

Comment: You would need to write some code... I see no attempt in your code.

Comment: it was enough for others.. and i got my answer. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could create one string and insert at the end

```
var htmlStr = '<ul>';
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    var place = results[i];
    htmlStr += '<li>'+ place.name + " - " + place.vicinity +'</li>';
  }
htmlStr += '</ul>';

document.getElementById("myPlace").innerHTML = htmlStr;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your code to following

```
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    var place = results[i];
    if (i == 0) {
       document.getElementById("myPlace").innerHTML = "<ul>"; // add ul tag for 1st item
    }
    document.getElementById("myPlace").innerHTML += "<li>" + place.name + " - " + place.vicinity + "</li>"; // add li for each item

    if(i == results.length -1) { // closing ul tag for last item
        document.getElementById("myPlace").innerHTML += "</ul>";
    }
  }
```

Comment: it didn't return any results

Comment: If it didn't return any results, do this: put `console.log(results[i]);` into the for loop, and see where it's failing. Hit F12 to view the developer console. Are you sure `"myPlace"` is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if i did not understand your question corretly, but you want to list the name and vicinity of each item on a ul-li tag ? If so you could do this.

```
<div id="myPlace">
</div>

var results = [{"name": "name 1", "vicinity" : "vicinity 1"},
              {"name": "name 2", "vicinity" : "vicinity 2"},
              {"name": "name 3", "vicinity" : "vicinity 2"}];

for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

    var ul = '<ul>';
    ul += '<li>'+results[i].name+'</li>';
    ul += '<li>'+results[i].vicinity+'</li>';
    ul += '</ul>';
    document.getElementById("myPlace").innerHTML += ul;

  }
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kxjybrvs/)

Comment: @charlietfl you are probably right, i think that also, but that's not what you get from reading the question

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly:

```
// Declare list outside the scope of the for loop.
var list = "<ul>";

for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) 
{
    var place = results[i];
    console.log(place)
    // Add the <li>name - vicinity</li> text
    list += "<li>" + place.name + " - " + place.vicinity + "</li>"; 
}
// Close the list.
list += "</ul>";
// Insert the new "list" data.
document.getElementById("myPlace").innerHTML += list;
```